# Summation change of index and limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation

My brain isn't working today (I thought this would be simple) but I can't figure out how to change from this summation equation

$ \sum _{n=1}^N a^n$

to this one

$ \sum _{j=1}^? [a^{2j-1} + a^{2j}] $

As an example, lets assume N=5. The first equation gives

$ \sum _{n=1}^5 a^n = a^1+a^2+a^3+a^4+a^5$

The second equation should give the same equation with odd-even pairs

$ \sum _{j=1}^? [a^{2j-1} + a^{2j}] = [a^1+a^2]+[a^3+a^4]+[a^5+0]$

I'm not sure what the upper limit on the summation of the second equation should be and how it is related to N? I feel like I need to introduce some kind of conditional coefficients in the second equation as well? The equation should hold for any value of N (odd or even) and NOT be cluttered with conditionals. I feel like there is a "text book" answer to this. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take it to the ceiling and floor it.
$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k = \sum_{k=1}^{\lceil n/2\rceil} a_{2k-1} + \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} a_{2k}$$

To test, this gives
$$\sum_{k=1}^5 a_k = \sum_{k=1}^{3} a_{2k-1} + \sum_{k=1}^{2} a_{2k} = (a_1 + a_3 + a_5) + (a_2+a_3)$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^6 a_k = \sum_{k=1}^{3} a_{2k-1} + \sum_{k=1}^{3} a_{2k} = (a_1 + a_3 + a_5) + (a_2+a_3+a_6)$$

Comment: Nice! I logically got the same answer after some tinkering, but I was having difficulty figuring out how to write it in summation notation... You got it exactly as I would have put it.

Comment: Very well put.  Concise, simple, and efficient!  Well done. +1

Comment: @Graham and others: OK...great answer! The only thing I'm curious/concerned about is how the mathematical community will view the use of "floor" and "ceil". In my original thought, I was considering using "mod" but that seems to belong to the world of programming and not a standard in mathematics. I just want to be sure I won't get any backlash for unconventional notation. That was actually the root of my question where, again, I thought there might be a text book answer.

Comment: @ThatsRightJack There's no problem then.  The floor and ceiling notation (also the sawtooth, $\{x\}$, for fractional part) are a well known convention.  They were originally introduced in the 1800's, and updated to their current notation in the 1960's.

Comment: @Graham Thanks for the insight! As you pointed out, I would expect that it would be well received, but sometimes mathematicians are very picky in their conventions...I'm not a mathematician so I thought I would ask. As for your answer...perfectly elegant and simple. I accept!